# Accidentally saved a csv file with 2 sheets - is there any way to restore the deleted sheet?

Tags: excel, csv

I forgot I was working on a csv file and not excel and saved it (either I didn't get the usual warning or I spaced out and ignored it). The most important sheet is the one that's been lost - is there any way to retrieve it? I'm working on a mac.

Comment: Sorry to say that most likely it is gone.  Your only hope is to see if there is still a temp file, but the fact that you saved it and closed would probably have removed the temp file.

Comment: You can see if this article is any help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/recover-files-in-office-for-mac-6c6425b1-6559-4bbf-8f80-4f038402ff02